# In typescript, how to export enum type defined in a module?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum type with many items and therefore I want to put the definition in an individual file.
The type is defined as

```js
const enum Band {
  B2190m = '2190m',
  B631m  = '631m',
   // ... etc. many more
};
```

However, trying to export this by `export` or `export default` fails with "Expression expected" TS1109.
What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const enum` is inlined while transpilation to js, so can't be exported.
You should emit "const" and use just enum:

```
export enum Band {
...
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it doesn't work for "plain enum", either. That was actually my first attempt, later I tried `const enum` as another possibility. I suspect there is some piece of TS documentation that I missed or did not understand. Never mind, I will read through the docs again.